# How to make everything other than face transparent

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to extract the face from an image using opencv. Initially I'm converting the image to grayscale like so

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Then I'm using dlib to generate facial points for me and then converting that to a numpy array and using fillconvexpoly method to get the face inside the face polygon

```
   #detect facial landmarks
   shape = predictor(gray, rect)
   #convert facial landmarks to numpy array
   shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)



   #initialize new array layout as shape
   remapped_shape = np.zeros_like(shape)
   xmin, ymin = shape.min(axis=0)
   xmax, ymax = shape.max(axis=0)

   feature_mask=np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],3),np.uint8)
   feature_mask[:]=(0,0,0)
   remapped_shape = face_remap(shape)

   cv2.fillConvexPoly(feature_mask, remapped_shape[0:27], [255, 255, 255])
   feature_mask = feature_mask.astype(np.bool)
   out_face[feature_mask] = image[feature_mask]
   cv2.imwrite("out_face.png", out_face)
```

I tried initializing feature_mask with

```
np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],4),np.uint8)
```

but that's giving me an error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (500,500,4)
```

How can I tweak my code to get the expected output

Here's the sample input[image]

Here's the output I'm getting

[image]

I want the background to be transparent rather than black

Comment: I already figured out the imagemagick way to remove the black background but would like to how my code can be tweaked to achieve the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a 4 channel `BGRA` or `RGBA` image to have transparency. I tweaked your code a little bit to fit this.

```
feature_mask=np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]),np.uint8)
remapped_shape = face_remap(shape)

cv2.fillConvexPoly(feature_mask, remapped_shape, [255])
out_face = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=feature_mask)

(x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(remapped_shape)
alpha = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)
feature_mask = feature_mask[y:y+h,x:x+w]
out_face = out_face[y:y+h,x:x+w]
alpha[feature_mask == 255] = 255

mv = []
mv.append(out_face)
mv.append(alpha)

out_face = cv2.merge(mv)
```

[image]